# Toast is not working in my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

i am a beginner android application developer. currently trying to build a simple calculator app nd want to show the calculated result by using Toast. but right now i am unable to use toast to display this output. there is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText input_field1,input_field2,result_field;
    int result_var;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void add_numbers(View v){

        input_field1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field1);
        String no1=input_field1.getText().toString();
        input_field2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field2);
        String no2=input_field2.getText().toString();
        int field1_int=Integer.parseInt(no1);
        int field2_int=Integer.parseInt(no2);
        result_field= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultfield);
        result_var=field1_int+field2_int;
        result_field.setText("result "+result_var);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result_var, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }   
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Substract" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/divide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Divide" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:text="Add" 
        android:onClick="add_numbers" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/field1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/resultfield"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/field2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have a Logcat error? If so, please include it.

Comment: does `result_field.setText("result "+result_var);` work?

Comment: 'editText1' is not defined

Comment: result_field.setText("result "+result_var); this code is working properly. if i commented toast part it is working properlly @modge

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need a string to be displayed in a toast. You are trying to display an int. The simplest thing to do is to wrap it with String using `String.valueOf()`.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(result_var), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

As a side note generally in java we wouldn't use underscores `_` in variable names. Better to name them like this.

```
EditText mInputField1,mInputField2,mResultField;
int mResultVar;
```

`m` for member variables.

Also better to put `findViewById` in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

result_var should be a string

```
String result_var="";
String Testing="testing";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result_var+testing, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Otherwise use as according to you:**

```
// if you have values of field1_int and field2_int

int result_var=field1_int+field2_int;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(result_var), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Toast message has to be `String`

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+result_var, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

A advice, as you are beginner. You should read the required arguments accepted by any method you are using.

[Read Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int))

For example in your case.

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+result_var, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(result_var), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```